# Can I use external clock as SCK in master mode (dspic33e)?

Tags: pic, spi

I am using a dspic33ep512mc806 and I want to use two different SPI modules with the same clock (not only at the same frequency but one clock shared by both modules) and both modules have to be master mode. I've tried to generate one clock from one SPI1 module and connected it to the SCK pin of SPI2 module but it doesn't work, i suppose because using SCK as input pin is a setting used only in slave mode. Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: The clock generator for the each SPI module does use the same clock in master mode (the instruction cycle clock, see [DS70569](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005185a.pdf)). However, I'm guessing by your question that you mean something else; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes the clock is the same but, when I activate both modules, the two clock starts at different time because I'am enabling with two different code lines. My primary requirement is that the two clocks have to be perfectly aligned so the only idea I've had was share the clock generating by one but I don't know how perform this in master mode.

Comment: I think your comment in response to kjgregory's answer highlights the underlying issue, which is that the dspic33 architecture likely doesn't support this. However, can you give more details about your application? It's unclear why you need to have two synchronous writes to two different slaves with what you've outlined in your question and there may be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to select the same clock source from the chip's internal clocking resources. You should be able to get the two clocks synced up that way.

Comment: I've selected the same internal source but when I activate the two modules I necessary enable two different registers so the clocks start at different time where the delay is associated to the CPU work for enabling them. I would want to parallelize these activations but I supposed this idea goes against the architecture of dsPIC. For this reason I've generated the clock from one module and tried to force it into SCK pin of an other module.

Comment: Well I'm fairly certain that you won't have success with forcing one clock onto the other externally. I would suggest coming through the programmers guide for a way to sync them. You may have to get creative.

Comment: I find a different solution for my problem! The final aim is to send two different blocks of data in two different wires but synchronized with one clock. So instead of using two spi modules as master I implement only one spi module with remappable pin as SDO. In this way changing the SDO pin I ensure that data will be transmitted in two different outputs but with the same synchronism. Thank you for your replies.